# Ubuntu 12.04 & Wine: No audio via HDMI

Tags: 12.04, sound, wine, hdmi

- Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and Wine 1.5.3 (official PPA); also briefly attempted to use Wine 1.4 (from repository).
- PC → HDMI → Receiver (plus speakers) → HDMI → TV

Totem outputs to HDMI (to the speakers), when the appropriate device is selected though the Sound panel, though any Wine‐based programs will not—I can only get output through my front headphone port; my preferred device is ignored by the Sound panel.

Also, I now cannot get audio to pass through to my TV’s internal speakers via any means.

I was not having any of these issues with Ubuntu 11.10 (fresh install).

Comment: This worked for me as I had the same issue, but hopefully someone will come along with an official solution.  Download the Pulse Audio Control from the software centre (Search for PAVcontrol) then select "HDMI Audio output"  I logged out and in again and then I had HDMI sound working through my TV (Wine apps included)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I couldn’t resolve the problem.

Here’s my lspci output:
`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a kernel issue. For radeon graphics the following seems to work:

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?62635-No-HDMI-sound-after-upgrade-to-Kubuntu-11.10-with-my-hd4770

Comment: Thanks for the info. I’m guessing this issue was resolved after I updated Linux from 3.2.0.23.25 to 3.2.0.24.26.